# Criar rotas - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, route

Bom, eu tenho esta rota definida no meu arquivo Routes :

`$route['novidades-e-estrategias-de-marketing-digital-em-nosso-blog/(.*)/(.*)']      = "blog/post_list/$1";`

Esta é a url :

`novidades-e-estrategias-de-marketing-digital-em-nosso-blog/19/sistema-de-crm-para-auxilio-ao-time-de-vendas`

Sendo que ela é formatada assim :

`return site_url(lang('list_route').'/'.$category->id.$preffix);`

Porém agora preciso deixar minha url neste formato :

`sistema-de-crm-para-auxilio-ao-time-de-vendas-catid-19`

Ou seja :

`base_url().$preffix.'-catid-'.$cateogory->id;`.

Minha pergunta é, com essas modificações, como faço minha rota?

Comment: Não entendi como vai ficar, mas o parâmetro numérico no CI é `(:num)`, basta você modificar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira :

```
$route["(.*)-catid-(:num)"]      = "blog/post_list/$2";
```